Kotlin can't infer non-nullability among two objects
When there's a pair of nullable objects in play, but the code has already ruled out the case where both are null, Kotlin can't seem to infer non-nullability for one when the other is null.
Here's the most basic minimum repro I could conceive of an issue I stumbled upon.
 
data class Foo(val x:Int, val y:Int)


class Demo {

    val table = hashMapOf<Int, Foo>()

    fun runDemo(index1:Int, index2:Int) : Int {

        var item1 = table[index1]
        var item2 = table[index2]

        if ((item1 == null) && (item2 == null)) {
            return 0
        }

        // We know at this point that either item1 or item2 can be null, but not both

        if (item1 == null) {
            item1 = item2.copy(x=0)    // compiler can't infer this is safe
        } else if (item2 == null) {
            item2 = item1.copy(x=0)    // OK
        }

        return item1.x + item1.y + item2.x + item2.y
    }
}

The item2.copy() statement generates the same error as it would for accessing any other nullable object that hasn't previously been tested: Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Foo?
But any human can infer that if item1 is null at this point in in the code, then item2 must be non-null. Is this just a limitation of how smart Kotlin can be when inferring non-null?  Or am I spacing out and missing an obvious edge case where item2 could be null at the moment of the copy method invocation?
Assuming I'm not mistaken about item2 is guaranteed to be null when item1 is, then what is the cleanest workaround. Ideas:

Change the errant line to item1 = item2!!.copy(x=0). Breaks coding standards, but I can probably justify it.

OR

Force an assert with requireNotNull or more redundant checks

        if (item1 == null) {
            item1 = item2?.copy(x=0)    // makes compiler happy
        } else if (item2 == null) {
            item2 = item1.copy(x=0)
        }

        requireNotNull(item1)  // impossible to assert
        requireNotNull(item2)  // impossible to assert

        return item1.x + item1.y + item2.x + item2.y   // OK


Or is there another Kotlinesque way to express what I'm trying to do?

If I understand correctly compiler will provide safe-cast only when it's unconditional which is not the case here. So you probably do need to use !! .

@Pawel - how is not unconditional?

It's about the first if check. Neither item1 nor item2 can be determined as always non-null there so it does not trigger any smart casting. And it appears compiler does not carry any assumptions or complex state like nullability relation between variables so smart cast won't suddenly appear in your second if block.

Essentially smart cast can only happen on variables that are actually used during a check - so validating item1 will never trigger a smart cast of item2.
